# Spring .NET setting a property value in config without instantiating the object

Tags: dependency-injection, spring.net

I am writing a TestClass let's say "`ServiceTest`" which has a property called `ExampleService`

```
public IService ExampleService { get; set;}
```

I am using the ExampleService inside my test method and invoking some operations on it.
I need to instantiate the IService using spring.config.
But as it is a Test class I do not want to create instance of ServiceTest inside my spring config. I know how to do that using  tag.

```
<object id="MyService" type="MyTestProject.ServiceTest, MyTestProject">
    <property name="ExampleService " ref="SomeAssembly.ServiceClass"/>
</object>
```

But I just want to set the value of ExampleService in my app.config so that it gets instantiated and set for the variable `ExampleService`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a unit test, you really do not want to start a spring context. There are mocking and auto-mocking frameworks out there that better suits the job of building a fake dependency:

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/ 
and 
http://code.google.com/p/moq/

If you are however in a integration test scenario than you should have a look at aliases (depending on your scenario you could use a dedicated alias file):
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#d4e596